# Slim Framework Sessions

Tags: php, session, slim

Is there a middleware for sessions in PHP Slim Framework? If not, is there a lightweight session library that works well with the Slim Framework? Its important that the library supports session storage in a database (MySQL).

Answer (score 3):

Slim session manager package can be used. It's available at:

https://github.com/yusukezzz/slim-session-manager

1. Composer based installation
2. Slim middleware
3. Can be used with any database driver

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

PHP native sessions can be database backed.

[PHP sessions in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272405/php-sessions-in-database)

It's pretty easy to use native PHP sessions, not sure why you'd need a library.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [Session Docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Sessions), they only have

- Native Session Store
- Cookie Session Store

It doesn't appear to have a database backed session. Maybe its in development or maybe there is a 3rd party plugin for it.

Comment: I understand, but which library would you use for sessions then? It should be lightweight..